# How do I import entity related fields using drush migration?

Tags: 8, users, migrations

I am trying to do data migration from a Drupal 7 site to a Drupal 8 site using **drush migration**. 
**Example:** I am trying to import users which has 5-7 fields and I tried to import fields using:

- d7_field
- d7_field_instance

These 2 are importing all fields in Drupal 7 (users, taxonomy, node). How can I restrict this to import only specific entity fields?

Comment: And after migration keeping the user fields and delete all others with a simple `foreach` in `hook_update_N` is no option?

Comment: In the first place itself using drush is there any option to restrict fields?. Because in my D7 site almost 250 fields are there. Can't import all fields and again run hook_update_N() to delete others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this via a custom migration module, this way you have full control over what will be migrated, note the bold text:

> - Create the migrations using drush migrate-upgrade --configure-only as discussed in Upgrade Using Drush
> - Make sure you have aconfig/syncdirectory, to which the next step will write
> - Export the migrations using drush config:export
> - Create your custom migration module
> - **Copy only the YML files you want** to use from the config/sync directory into the config/install directory of your new custom module, editing them to remove the uuid values and to edit the id, group, label, and other values as needed
> - In the config/install directory of your new custom module, make a new migrate_plus.migration_group.your_module.yml file for your new migration group.

from official handbook: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/upgrade/customize-migrations-when-upgrading-to-drupal-8

You can also rename the fields. Further processing can happen in `hook_migrate_prepare_row()`, `hook_migration_plugins_alter()`, or even a custom process plugin.

#### update

Please note that you will *not* be exporting configuration from a site and moving it to other site. Config export is a bad name here. Read it as *generate migration template*.

When you generated your template (aka, exported), you handpick those fields, entities and configuration that you want from all the available generated files, put them in a custom module, say `my_custom_mig`, enable it, and run it's migration.

Comment: We are trying to do this via drush migration, not with config export. And also I am asking "User" entity as an example here. What if I want to do for an article entity or vocabulary. I can't export the config and import it manually. So I want to do it via drush migration.

Comment: @Ajay Reddy can you please update the question to reflect your requirements?

Comment: @AjayReddy answer updated.

Comment: @hkoosha Thanks for the idea. This is not the exact solution for me but the idea of using **hook_migrate_prepare_row()** works for me and I did some customizations on this.